# GDB detaching when forked child is killed

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am able to debug a parent process along with any child processes that it forks off with GDB. In the parent, I invoke the kill() linux system function on the the child process, but for some reason this also terminates the parent process. I am debugging remotely on a target (192.168.0.1) using gdbserver.

This is the output from GDB after invoking the kill() function:

```
Child terminated with signal = 0x9 (SIGKILL)
Connection to 192.168.0.1 closed.
```

When running without GDB, the parent process continues execution after the kill commmand, which is ideal.

I also use the following GDB options to allow child debugging:

```
set follow-fork-mode child
set detach-on-fork off
set schedule-multiple on
```